# composer нет vendor/autoload

Tags: php, telegram-bot, composer

Скачал библиотеку, github telegram-bot-sdk
она работает по compose, т.к. руки из одного места просто взял чей-то код,

```
include('vendor/autoload.php'); //Подключаем библиотеку
use Telegram\Bot\Api;
```

как блин подключить эту библиотеку, если я 0 в php а файла venodr autoolaod у меня нет?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно изначально сделать `composer init` и после установить библиотеку `composer require irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk` тогда появится папка `vendor`

Comment: composer init делаю, оно говорит package name, я ему telegram-bot-sdk а оно посылает? что не так делаю?

Comment: Находясь в консоли, перейдите в папку проекта и введите команду установки composer require irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Comment: @Meow Root package 'irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk' cannot require itself in its composer.json уже пробовал, такой ответ

Comment: Создайте новую папку и повторите установку библиотеки в неё.

Comment: 'composer init делаю, оно говорит package name, я ему telegram-bot-sdk а оно посылает' в package name нужно писать имя своего проекта, а не пакета который хотите установить